# Unable to access website hosted on virtual machine

Tags: centos, iptables, virtualbox, firewall, webserver

I'm on a mac (osx 10.9.3) running CentOS7 in virtualbox. I would like to access the website hosted on the virtual machine. Browsing to the Guest IP returns webpage not available.

I'm able to `ping` and `ssh` to the VM.
I've set bridged adapter for the network settings in the VM.
I've given `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` Listen 80 and host IP address.
`telnet` and `curl` to Guest IP returns connection refused.

I'm guessing it's a firewall / iptables configuration problem where I need to allow the host. How do I configure CentOS firewall / iptables to allow host?

Comment: post your firewall rules: `service iptables status` please, and be sure that `httpd` is running `service httpd status`

Comment: CentOS7 doesn't recognize service command.. really annoying

Comment: try `/etc/init.d/httpd status`

Comment: returns "no such file or directory" Isn't there an official alternative to these commands? Or a download to get them. example: I needed to download net-tools to get ifconfig to work..

Comment: The modern commands would be `systemctl status httpd` and `systemctl status iptables`.

Answer (score 2):

you are able to ping and ssh to the VM, So I guess it is not a firewall problem, I guess your httpd service isn't running:

try to run it using:

```
service httpd start
```

or:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd start
```

httpd should installed on centos by default!!!!, to install httpd you can simply do this on centos:

```
yum install httpd
```

to set the apache service to start on boot(to avoid such a problem again):

```
chkconfig httpd on
```

Comment: httpd is installed. I'm having problems with starting the httpd service. Both service httpd start and /etc/init.d/httpd start don't work. I'll look into getting these commands working, thank you. If this gets it working i'll accept answer

Comment: Apache is running. '/bin/systemctl status httpd.service' returns 'active(running)' and in 'ps -aux' there are about 5 processes called apache. Still can't acces the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Open your firewall to allow connections.

e.g.,

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http

sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https

sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```